# A question about a lemma in Kenneth Kunen's article "Some points in $\beta \mathbb{N}$."

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

The article reference is: Kunen, K. (1976). Some points in βN. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 80(3), 385-398. doi:10.1017/S0305004100053032.

I am stuck in lemma 5.2 which says: Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a selective ultrafilter and $(\mathcal{M}, v)$ a non-atomic measure algebra. Then, in $V^{\mathcal{M}}$, there is  no $\mathcal{P}$-point extending $\mathcal{U}$. The proof goes like this:

"Define a finitely additive measure $\rho$ on $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ in $V^{\mathcal{M}}$ as follows. If $[[x\subseteq \omega]]=1$, define a measure $\sigma_x$ on $\mathcal{M}$ (in $\mathcal{V}$) by

$\sigma_x(b)=\mathcal{U}- \lim (v([[n\in x]] \wedge b):n\in \omega)$.

$\sigma_x$ may be identified with an $\mathcal{M}$-valued element of $[0,1]$, which we call $\rho(x)$.  "

(The following is the assertion which i'm troubling with:)

"Since $\mathcal{M}$ is non-atomic, $\rho$ is with value 1 non-atomic. "

Why is $\rho$ with value 1, non-atomic?

Sorry if the question is too little elaborate, but is something very specific I need to understand. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It would help much if you would define some terms and notation. What is a $selective$ ultrafilter?  What is $[[ \cdot ]]?$ In the def'n of $\sigma_x$ is that a limit as $n\to \infty$? And I cannot make grammatical sense of the assertion in quotes, that you have trouble with, but apparently that's what K. Kunen wrote.